# How to tweak Windows swapping priority (if there is some?)

Tags: memory, windows-server-2012, swap

Sometimes I open a program that allocates too much memory - i.e. computer has 0.5 gb free ram, and an application requests 1gb.

In this case, it will start swapping so it can fulfill the request.

Problem is: it is doing **extreme** swapping, including services' memory, so the computer gets very slow - even the mouse pointer starts stuttering and sometimes I have to power cycle the machine.

It feels wrong to me that an user-mode program, running from a normal user account, can bring the machine down.

Is there some way to say to Windows: hey, if an app requests too much memory put **its** memory to swap and not essential services' memory.

OS is Windows Server 2012 x64, but I've seen this in numerous other machines as well.

Comment: How much ram and how much swap do you have allocated?

Comment: There’s no way the swap algorithm would evict recently used pages. Instead, you’re looking at IO starvation. Your storage is just too slow.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have 3.5 GB RAM, and the program is Google Earth which sometimes enters a sort of loop and aloocates 4+ GB of memory.

Comment: @DanielB As a test I tried removing the swapfile from the C: drive and moving it to an array of separate, 2 disks combined with striping. It worked - the machine does not hang anymore - so the problem is Swap I/O competing with other I/O on the same disk. But this still bugs me - an unprivileged user mode application can allocate enough memory to trigger swapping, effectively DoSing the machine by preventing other, non-swapping I/O from happening. Is there anyway to prevent this aside from moving the swapfile to another disk - in case there isn't another disk in the machine?

Comment: Having the pagefile on C: along with the OS and program you're running may not be optimal, but should work fine under normal circumstances.  Have you tested your C: partition (and the drive it lives on) for errors?

Comment: install more memory.  4GB for any modern machine is pretty low.

Comment: @Keltari unfortunately it's not that a modern machine, it actually has 4GB but the chipset only recognizes up to 3.5 GB (500MB are "hardware reserved") and I can't afford anything better. Now that I've solved the practical issue by putting the pagefile out of C:, this becomes more of a theoretical question

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the hard-drive is OK, although it has almost 18,000 hours of experience on the resume. A faster one would be nice, but I can't afford any upgrade at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1006263/how-to-tweak-windows-swapping-priority-if-there-is-some?noredirect=1#comment1392968_1006263), Daniel B says I was experiencing I/O starvation, so I tried moving the swap-file out of the system partition (C:) and into a separate **disk**.

It worked - when under memory pressure, the computer does not stop responding anymore. I then decided to do some research on the issue, in order to understand **why** this happens. These are my conclusions:

1. In an official Microsoft document titled ["I/O Prioritization in Windows Vista"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/Priorityio.doc), it is stated that I/O is hierarchically processed, and that *all critical-priority I/O must be processed before any other priority I/O*.
2. It is also said that *critical priority I/O is reserved to the memory manager*.
3. I couldn't find evidence of the existence of any special prioritization by the memory manager based on the owner of a page (i.e. swapping of memory pages allocated by lower priority processes getting lower I/O priority as well).
4. I couldn't find any evidence of new prioritization strategies in Windows 8.

So, assuming that all memory manager I/O has the same (critical) priority and that the I/O strategy is unchanged since Vista, this is the recipe for disaster:

- Swap-file in the same disk as the system (usually C:)
- A process requests more memory than is physically available in the system.
- Swapping occurs. While swapping is happening, no other I/O operation can take place, even essential I/O by system services or other components of the kernel, because critical I/O is reserved to the memory manager AND all critical I/O takes place before any other I/O.
- Gradually, every process that blocks on I/O gets stuck. Ultimately the system is effectively unresponsive.